# Woocommerce Product Variation customize ul li blocks

Tags: woocommerce, product-variations

Anybody can shed a light on how to create [this kind](https://hk.lignosus.com/product/lignosus-best-natural-respiratory-health-supplement/) of product variation selection?

Instead of a dropdown, it displays product variations as a radio button list.

It converts  to

list, is it via customized PHP or elementor will be able to do it?

[image]

I checked the source doesn't seem like a plugin can do that.

Comment: I checked the source, it is fairly simple and not using variation swatch plugin. It should be using ACF (advance custom fields) but I couldn't find tutorial regarding this though.

Comment: Are these actually product variations, or is it simply a quantity selector?

Comment: frm the source code it is using woocommerce product variations for this function.

Comment: You have 2 ways of doing it - using variation product or grouped product (depends on how you want to work ). You need to modify the templates for both eitherway to get this result. The templates you need to update / modify are located Woo -> templates -> single product -> add-to-cart -> variable.php or grouped.php . You will need to add your own js logic to update the selection. https://woo.com/document/template-structure/